# Getting different date in database record after insert client date

Tags: asp.net

I need help please,
I've problem when I insert client datetime using DateTime.Now.ToString() , I got the server date instead

```
 try
    {

        c.SP_Introduction("SP_INS_INVOICE");
        c.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
        c.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestId", int.Parse(txtRequestId.Text));
        c.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", int.Parse(Session["UserId"].ToString()));
        SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@InvoiceId", SqlDbType.Int);
        parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        c.cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);
        int i = c.cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string _InvoiceId = c.cmd.Parameters["@InvoiceId"].Value.ToString();
        c.conn.Close();
        c.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        if (i >= 1 || i == -1)
        {
            Session["InvoiceId"] = _InvoiceId;
            Response.Redirect("InvoicePayment.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error", "AlertError('Error..!','Somthing went wrong....!');", true);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Error", "AlertError('Error..!','" + ex.Message.ToString() + "');", true);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what *client* you are using?

Comment: Repace DateTime.Now.ToString() with  TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Your Country Standard Time")).ToString(); and in place of "Your Country" just write the name of country.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this line:

```
c.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString()));
```

with

```
c.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvoiceDate", Convert.ToDateTime(dateFromClientApp));
```

Depending on the *calling* application, you will need to make sure the date isn't culture-specific if you're looking to store the date based on the region the application is used in.  Also, if you're looking to save the time portion of the date, consider using UTC, take a look at this [article](http://ttps://dev.to/corykeane/3-simple-rules-for-effectively-handling-dates-and-timezones-1pe0).